# LuaSockets library will not correctly load

Tags: c, lua, raspberry-pi, luasocket

So, I've been annoyingly trying to work with LuaSockets2.0.2, and when I try to use it, I get the following error:

```
lua5.1: /media/pi/Cruzer/Lua/flywheels.lua:7: module 'luasocket.c' not       found:
no field package.preload['luasocket.c']
no file './luasocket/c.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/luasocket/c.lua'
no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/luasocket/c/init.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/luasocket/c.lua'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/luasocket/c/init.lua'
no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/luasocket/c.lua'
no file '/usr/share/lua/5.1/luasocket/c/init.lua'
no file './luasocket/c.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/luasocket/c.so'
no file '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lua/5.1/luasocket/c.so'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/luasocket/c.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
no file './luasocket.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/luasocket.so'
no file '/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lua/5.1/luasocket.so'
no file '/usr/lib/lua/5.1/luasocket.so'
no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
stack traceback:
[C]: in function 'require'
/media/pi/Cruzer/Lua/flywheels.lua:7: in main chunk
[C]: ?
```

Running it with only Lua gives me the same problem. I read through the LuaSocket documentation, checked over my third-edition Lua book, and tried to do a handful of other things, but I didn't get any  *different*  results.

I'm trying to make something that will allow me to send a TCP message to an IP to first see if it's up, and second, see if it will send back data, as it's for an experiment/project thing I'm doing. I'm also using a Raspberry Pi 2+.

I understand that it says it's missing these Lua files. `local socket = require("sockets")` gives me a similar error, and trying `require("socket")` or `require("sockets.lua")` all still give me an error. Nothing currently appears to work, so what should I do?

Comment: try `local socket = require("socket")`

Comment: well, `local socket = require("socket")` yields a similar error.